# Rails 4 - nested attributes are not saved

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, nested, grails-orm

I have these models:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :company_services, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :services, through: :company_services
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :services, :allow_destroy => true
end
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :company_services
  has_many :companies, through: :company_services
end
class CompanyService < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :service
  validates_uniqueness_of :service_id, scope: :company_id
end
```

Then in the controller action:

```
  def new
    @company = Company.new
    @company.services.build
  end
  def create
    ...
    @company = Company.new(company_params)
respond_to do |format|
      if @company.save
        format.html { redirect_to edit_company_path(@company), notice: 'Company was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @company }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new', notice: 'Company could not be saved.' }
        format.json { render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    params.require(:company).permit(:name, :email, ..., {:service_ids => [:id, :name, :label, :icon, :service_type]}).merge(latlng: geocode)
```

And view:

```
<%= simple_form_for @company do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.association :services, 
                             as: :check_boxes, 
                             label_method: :label, 
                             value_method: :id,
                             item_wrapper_class: 'manage_services',
                             label: 'Services' %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

The checkboxes are rendered properly, ut when I save the form, the services are not saved.
I tried also

```
{:service_ids => []}
```

in `permit` in the controller, but that returned this error:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

I stuck here yesterday and still cannot figure it out... I found also some similar topics here on SO, but none of them helped me.

What I have wrong here?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**
Here's the list of parameters I get after sending out the form:

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"igyh4EBcdXT5b3rj/Zy52Mi27dh4u81GWCtUmGNCXw4=",
>   "company"=>{"company_name"=>"0", ..., "service_ids"=>["2", "7", "12",
>   "17", "22", "27", "32", ""], "mc_num"=>"3512616", "dot_num"=>"126126",
>   ...}, "commit"=>"Update"}

Comment: As mentioned in the OP, I've tried this, but this returns `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: This is good thing, it means it actually tries to assign it instead of completely ignoring your data. Digging into what it actually means. Any backtrace for that error?

Comment: Yeah; when I put some column names into the array for `service_ids`, there's no error, but fields `services` fields are not saved.

Comment: If I understand what the SimpleForm gem is doing, you will only receive the array of service_ids representing the checkboxes that were checked.  The goal of the association helper would be the same as saying "company.service_ids = [1, 3, 5]" which creates a direct assignment of the services (adding/dropping CompanyServices as required).  This is NOT the same as using nested attributes.

As such, adding service_ids to your permitted attribute list should allow you to save properly: params.require(:company).permit(:name, :email, ..., :service_ids).

Comment: Hi @AndyV, thanks for the comment. I've tried this option, the result is that `services` are not saved, only the `company`. Scratching my head over this.

Comment: Can you post the params that are posted back?

Comment: Andy, please see the the output in the OP. Thank you.

Comment: First of all, your parameter is called "company_name", but you permit :name. Is it typo or not?

Comment: The params are what I expected to see.  Based on what they show, here is what the code suggests you are doing.  (1) You have already created a set of Service records. (2) The form is presented to create a new Company record that will be ASSOCIATED with 0..* of the previously created Services.  (3) After posting you should see new CompanyService records that reflect the Company-Service association based on the checkboxes  selected in the UI.   Your description of the problem, however, suggests that you want to create new Service records in addition Company.  Can you clarify your goal?